# MSSQL case statement - If the time is midnight then false, else true

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to build a case statement that follows the logic below:

```
If the time of the date provided is midnight(00:00:00) then false(0), else true(1)
```

I am looking to present this in a view that lists a number of orders sent down to schedule delivery, where midnight is our default time (and since deliveries do not happen at midnight, this would mean it has not been scheduled yet, setting it to 0/false. This will be used as a condition to show either a red cross or green tick on a web interface.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the field's type? You can convert/cast to `time` to get just the time part from a `datetime` field, eg `cast(somefield as time)`. Using a date or time field as a schedule flag is a very bad idea. Missing values are represented by `NULL` in the first place. Using a field to mean two different things will cause serious problems as well.

Comment: The field type at the moment is `datetime`. Unfortunately this is the only feasible way to check whether something has been scheduled or not; this view is being used to present a list of orders that have "been sent to delivery team" to act as a failsafe when our GeniusConnect application fails, so that we can manually add them via another SQL table. The world of quick fixes, I'm afraid.

EDIT: I'd also like to add I didn't build this database initially and no flag for when GeniusConnect doesn't import to Outlook was implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST([my-datetime] AS TIME) = '00:00:00.0000000' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM [my-table];
```

Comment: This did it for me. Brilliant. Thank you, Lunc!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  case WHEN CONVERT(nvarchar(10), myDate, 108)='00:00:00' then 0 else 1 END 
statement FROM [my-table];
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS SHOULD WORK

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (midnight DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES
('2012-06-18T10:34:09'),('2018-09-25T10:54:31'),('2018-09-25T00:00:00'),
('2018-09-25T12:07:09'),('2017-05-06T00:00:00'),('2016-08-19T08:11:35')

SELECT
midnight,
CAST(midnight AS TIME),
CASE WHEN CAST(midnight AS TIME)='00:00:00' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'midnight_Col'
FROM @TBL
```